# Hide applet parameters in JSP / include applet parameters from external js

Tags: applet

Recently, i have embedded a third party applet for the web project.

The applet provides some predefined parameters and i can use it into JSP file. For example:

```
<APPLET CODEBASE="XXXXX" .......>
    <PARAM NAME="downloadLink" value="http://xxxxxxxxx?imageId=xxxx">
</APPLET>
```

However, i think it is not security due to the parameters and its value can be viewed through "view source" function which provided by the browser. Therefore, users can get the download link easily and re-download the image by typing the link in address bar.

In the above situation,
1. How can i avoid the parameter and its value displayed in jsp source? 
2. is it possible to load the parameter list from java script/html/json etc...?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what level of security you want.
What probably would work for most users and solve your 'looking at the html source' problem is:

You could encrypt your parameters on the server and then pass them to your applet (with the 'param' parameter as you did) and then decrypt those params in your applet again. Then you won't see anything meaningful when you look at the html source. However a user could theoretically decompile the applet and extract the key and thus decrypt your params... So as mentioned it depends on the level of security you need.